# Morphism from the Koszul associative cooperad into the Koszul Lie cooperad?

Tags: operads, a-infinity-algebras

Thinking about whether or not there is a natural way to transform $L_\infty$-algebras into $A_\infty$-algebras, I wonder if there is a morphism of cooperads

$\mathcal{A}ss^i\to\mathcal{L}ie^i$

from the Koszul symmetric, associative cooperad $\mathcal{A}ss^i$ to the Koszul Lie cooperad $\mathcal{L}ie^i$. I think there is *no* such map and my argument is as follows:

Suppose there is such a map. Since 
$\mathcal{A}ss^i\simeq \mathcal{S}\otimes_H\mathcal{A}ss^*$ and 
$\mathcal{L}ie^i\simeq \mathcal{S}\otimes_H\mathcal{C}om^*$ (with $\otimes_H$ the tensor product of cooperads), this would imply that there is although a cooperad map

$id_\mathcal{S}\otimes_H \theta : \mathcal{S}\otimes_H\mathcal{A}ss^* \to 
\mathcal{S}\otimes_H\mathcal{C}om^*$, which in turn would mean that the map

$\theta : \mathcal{A}ss^* \to \mathcal{C}om^*$ exists, too. This however is not true, since both $\mathcal{A}ss$ as well as $\mathcal{C}om$ are finite dimensional in each arity and there is no morphism of operads $\mathcal{C}om\to\mathcal{A}ss$.

Is this a valid argument?

Comment: Because of the universality of the tensor product. Maybe there are other automorphism on $\mathcal{S}$ then $1$, but that wouldn't change the argument I think.

Comment: It seems nonstandard to call $Lie^i$ the "Koszul Lie cooperad" There is a cooperad governing Lie coalgebras and it's not that one.

Comment: I mean the Koszul dual of the Lie operad (in contrast to the *linear* dual). It's personal taste, I justthink it sounds better.

Comment: Your argument is essentially correct (modulo the 0 morphism from $Com$ to $Ass$). Rather than worrying about automorphisms of $S$ you could just tensor by $S^{-1}$ to get $\theta$. But I'm not sure that this question is mathoverflow appropriate.

Comment: It might not be appropriate, right. But I wasn't sure if this is appropriate for math.stackexchange either. I'm fine with a vote for close or a transit to math.stackexchange. Don't want to delete it though, since I think its interesting nontheless.